# Java threads pool - Which type and how many?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a program which runs in multiple iterations.
On each loop, I am starting up to 3000 concurrent threads, where some of them starts during the iteration and ends before the end of iteration, and some of them are stared and keep living until the end of the iteration.

For each iteration I recreate the threads.

1. Which type of executor should I best use: FixedThreadPool? ThreadPoolExecutor? Other?
2. If I need to set the number of thread values - max, min, fixed, any other... - how should I determine them?
3. Should I create a new Future object for each thread submission to keep track on its status?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3000 concurrent threads is way too high for any present time hardware.  the size of the pool should reflect the capabilities of the hardware (number of CPU cores).  You will need to experiment with different sizes to get optimal results but with 3000 concurrent threads you are just getting them starved.

What you need is to utilize a queue where you add tasks to it in the loop and worker threads that pull from the queue and do the tasks.  the worker threads will come fron a limited-size thread pool.

So you definitely want to you a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that operates on a given queue.  the [javadoc of the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) has useful information regarding strategies for queuing.

Comment: Thanks Sharon. 1. Will it be wise to set the ThreadPoolExecutor ctor argument of  maximumPoolSize to availableProcessors() value? 2.Can I actually use the pool for any thread type? 3. Following qn 2, will it be wise to define the pool as a singleton object?

Comment: like i said, pool size depends on many factors. you will have to experiment to get optimal results. you can start with availableProcessors and tweak with trial and error. the executor can be singleton. (or even public static var)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions first, I usually use FixedThreadPool, and the best number of threads is usually the number of cores in your machine (`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`).

For creating new Future objects, it depends; if you need to collect the data later, of course you need the Future to do so?

As an extension, I'd suggest you look into `ForkJoinPool`. It's a type of task meant for splitting work and reassembling the results back together.

Answer (score 1):

Well any calculation regarding number of threads (min/max etc) is not that straight and it requires knowledge of your work load and hardware. For e.g., if your tasks are completely CPU bound then  theoretically best configuration would be thread number = number of cores, whereas if your threads are IO bound ( for e.g., making calls to database, network etc ) then this number would be greater. Also you need to factor in any user level applications or default OS processes running on your system. Plus each thread in java has a stack memory associated with it which will accumulate with the number of threads. Another factor is size of  task queue of thread pool which will also add to memory. The best advise could be - start with number of cores available `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads and then profile. Most probably you would arrive at a number where your performance/throughput is maximum and then on further increase of thread number it falls.